# How to compose existing generators in our own ESM-based generator

Tags: es6-modules, yeoman-generator

I’m authoring a custom ESM generator using TypeScript.
I’m having a hard time finding documentation for composing existing generator.

Is there any documentation available ?
Is this possible ? If so how one would achieve such features.

I have created a simple [`generator-readme`](https://github.com/springcomp/generator-readme/tree/esm) to demonstrate the issue I have.

I’m having a hard time trying to [compose with the existing `generator-license` generator](https://github.com/springcomp/generator-readme/blob/42d3b7ef75d0f0b3f933dd9a8c16beda81d4ce9d/generators/app/App.ts#L64):

```js
import GeneratorLicense, { LicenseOptions } from 'generator-license';

export class App extends Generator<AppOptions> {

  …

  public async default() {

    if (this.options.license) {
      console.log(import.meta.url);
      const path = resolve('generator-license', import.meta.url);
      console.log(path);
      const licenseOpts: LicenseOptions = {
        publish: false,
      };
      this.composeWith<GeneratorLicense>('license', [], licenseOpts);
    }
  }
  …
}
```